# Granting Access via through SSH on AWS CodeCommit Repo to an Ionic Apps Build

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, npm, ssh

**Goal:**

So I am working with a project where I created a private library in Angular and saved it to an AWS code-commit repository.

I want to install this library to my Ionic app which I can then use freely within the application via **npm**.

**Version:**

Ionic 4.2.0 (Angular build)

**First Try:**

I first tried to npm install it using an HTTPS Git Credentials url in the **package.json** which allowed me to install it locally; after putting in the appropriate credentials my libraries functionality worked the way it should. When I pushed this project to the ionic dashboard and did a build on the ionic dashboard it gave me an error clarifying that it cannot access the AWS repo.

```
[17:22:05]: ▸ npm ERR!
[17:22:05]: ▸ npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/*url*': The requested URL returned error: 403
[17:22:05]: ▸ npm ERR!
```

After some thought this makes sense as there is no way for ionic to have access to a repo via HTTPS.

So I moved towards the use of SSH as Ionic has the settings of using public SSH keys.

**Second Try:**

I already have an Ionic SSH key setup with my Ionic pro Account where I currently have my project. So I believe that I could just copy this public key to the Amazon IAM User SSH and I should then be able to still npm install my library locally and on the ionic dashboard build.

I changed my url for the library to the SSH url in the package.json and ran an `npm install`

Well the console gave me the following error locally and on the Ionic Dashboard Build:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/*url*
npm ERR!
npm ERR! user@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

So now I cannot access it on my local machine or on ionic.

I researched a bit into this issue and the aws docs to SSH are not very helpful and ionic is also quiet on this issue.

**Questions:**

- Is there a possibility in hooking up an Ionic Dashboard app to have access to private repos on an `npm install` without using SSH?
- If there is no other way except using SSH, what are some hints and steps to take to debug or perhaps clarify my public SSH key works locally?
- Lastly, after it works locally, what is the best way into hooking it up with the Ionic dashboard? (**Note:** I already have an ssh key to grant me access to push and pull to this repo which stands alone from my Macs public ssh key. I don't want to lose access by implementing a second ssh key.)